# .NET Core EndRequest Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm builing **ASP.NET Core MVC** application and I need to have **EndRequest** event like I had before in **Global.asax.**

How I can achieve this?

Comment: I think this is duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705830/how-to-implement-global-asax-events-by-owin

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's as easy as creating a middleware and making sure it gets registered as soon as possible in the pipeline.

For example:

```
public class EndRequestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public EndRequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Do tasks before other middleware here, aka 'BeginRequest'
        // ...

        // Let the middleware pipeline run
        await _next(context);

        // Do tasks after middleware here, aka 'EndRequest'
        // ...
    }
}
```

The call to `await _next(context)` will cause all middleware down the pipeline to run. After all middleware has been executed, the code *after* the `await _next(context)` call will be executed. See the [ASP.NET Core middleware docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) for more information about middleware. Especially this image from the docs makes middleware execution clear:
[image: Middleware pipeline]

Now we have to register it to the pipeline in `Startup` class, preferably as soon as possible:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<EndRequestMiddleware>();

    // Register other middelware here such as:
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it will be invoked before request ends?

Comment: @Vnuuk I've updated my answer. I also suggest you read into the [docs about middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware).